# Concat string in Html.ActionLink()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I create a link with the Html.ActionLink(). I add parameter string to the url based on the condition of the query string that I get from URL.

```
<% 
strA = Request.QueryString["AA"];
strB = Request.QueryString["BB"];
strC = Request.QueryString["CC"];

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strA))
{
%>
   <%: Html.ActionLink(a.Name, Model.ActionName, Model.ControllerName, 
       new {aa = strA , tab = 2}, null)%>
<%
}else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strB)){
%>
   <%: Html.ActionLink(a.Name, Model.ActionName, Model.ControllerName, 
       new {bb = strB , tab = 2}, null)%>
<%
}else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strA) &&  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strB)){
%>
   <%: Html.ActionLink(a.Name, Model.ActionName, Model.ControllerName, 
       new {aa = strA , bb = strB, tab = 2}, null)%>
<%else{ %>
   <%: Html.ActionLink(a.Name, Model.ActionName, Model.ControllerName, 
       new {tab = 2}, null)%>
<% }%>
```

This is what I tried to do :

```
 <%
 string url_add =  "";
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strA))
 {  
  url_add += "aa=strA";
 }else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strB)){
  url_add += "bb=strB";
 }else if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strA) &&  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strB)){
  url_add += "aa=strA&bb=strB";
 }else{
  url_add += "tab=2";
 }
 %>
```

After I concat the string ready, I put that string as below :

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("My link", "my_action", "my_controller", new {url_add} , null) %>
```

But When I did this, my url will `"blahblah.com/url_add=aa=strA"`.

Could anyone show me the better solution please.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

titi,

the problem is related to the fact that you are attempting to add a single property 'object' to the routevalues dictionary, i.e. :

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("My link", "my_action", "my_controller", new {url_add} , null) %>
```

in this case, you are adding the routevalue: `new {url_add}` which is purely the concatenated string that you've built up. This routevalue NEEDS to be a keyvalue pair, so your approach of concatenating and adding a single variable just won't work.

I'd suggest that you try something along the lines of building a brand new routevalues dictionary 'within' the logic flow and only adding it onto the actionlink at the very end (i.e. the build of the actionlink only occurs once in the final line of your logic).

e.g.

```
var newRoutes = new RouteValueDictionary();
// if condition for strA matches
newRoutes.Add("aa", strA);
// if condition for strb matches
newRoutes.Add("bb", strB);
```

hope this gives a few ideas.

**[edit]** - in response to your comments below, here's your required overload including the @class object:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("My link", "my_action", "my_controller", newRoutes, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "selectedQ" } }) %>
```

Comment: Thanks jim. Anyway do I have to put this block of code in Global.asax.cs or where?

Comment: titi - this little block could be added to the existing code where you define the strA variables etc

Comment: jim, I tried to add link  `<%: Html.ActionLink("My link", "my_action", "my_controller", new {newRoutes} , null) %>` , but the url is `blahblah.com/My_controller/My_action?newRoutes=System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary`.

Comment: Update : Now It works well with `<%: Html.ActionLink("My link", "my_action", "my_controller",newRoutes, null) %>`

Comment: But I have a problem while I want to add link like this : `<%: Html.ActionLink("My link", "my_action", "my_controller",newRoutes, new { @class = "selectedQ" }) %>`.

Comment: titi - i've had a look at your problem on the 2nd overload. here's what you need to code that as: `Html.ActionLink("My link", "my_action", "my_controller", newRoutes, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "selectedQ" } })` (see edit above)